# How does an Elsevier article have all-hyperlink references?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls, elsarticle

I am going to submit a paper in an Elsevier journal. However, I notice that some of the references in a published paper have hyperlinks. Is it put by the journal or should I put it manually? If I should, how can I do this? See [this example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417421009805).

Specifically, here is an entry in my bib file

```
@article{auer2002EXP3,
   author = {Peter Auer and Nicolò Cesa-Bianchi and Yoav Freund and Robert E Schapire},
   doi = {10.1137/S0097539701398375},
   issue = {1},
   journal = {SIAM Journal on Computing},
   pages = {48-77},
   title = {The Nonstochastic Multiarmed Bandit Problem},
   volume = {32},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539701398375},
   year = {2002},
}
```

However, it shows that [image]
That is not what I want, what I want is something like the following, where the URL is not explicit [image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. Then what should I do? Can I submit my paper without considering this blue hyperlink

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert the formatted bibliographic entries to all-hyperlink objects if your goal is to submit a paper to an Elsevier-stable journal.

You didn't mention *which* journal you're eyeing; almost every Elsevier journal has its own formatting requirements that can differ in subtle and sometimes not so subtle ways from other jounrnal's formatting requirements. I would therefore pay close attention to *your* journal's submission requirements for LaTeX-based documents. Among them will likely be a statement as to which bibliography style you should employ. Elsevier actually distributes several BibTeX bibliography style files; among them are `elsarticle-harv.bst` (for documents with authoryear-style, aka "Harvard style", citation call-outs) and `elsarticle-num.bst` (for documents with numeric-style citation call-outs). Again, I would pay very close attention to your journal's specific formatting requirements, including those that pertain to generating the bibliography and the citation call-outs.

Here's how the bib entry you list in your query gets formatted if the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style is employed. (Note that the BibTeX field name `issue` is not recognized by the `elsarticle-harv` style; the field name ought to be `number`.)

[image]

Incidentally, I can't see much purpose in providing both `url` and `doi` fields, especially if the fields point to the same underlying webpage.

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{auer2002EXP3,
  author  = {Peter Auer and Nicolò Cesa-Bianchi and Yoav Freund 
            and Robert E. Schapire},
  journal = {SIAM Journal on Computing},
  title   = {The Nonstochastic Multiarmed Bandit Problem},
  year    = {2002}, 
  volume  = {32}, 
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {48--77},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539701398375}, 
  doi     = {10.1137/S0097539701398375},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP posted a comment that they intend to post their paper to a journal -- Expert System with Application -- that requires citation call-outs and bibliographic entries to be formatted according to the APA7 guidelines. To the best of my knowledge, there is no BibTeX-based implementation (yet) of the formatting guidelines of APA7. (There *is* a BibTeX-based implementation of the *APA6* guidelines: the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style.) However, there *is* a biblatex-based implementation of the APA7 guidelines; it may be accessed by executing `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` in the preamble.

Now, the `elsarticle` document class is *not* compatible with  the `biblatex` package. However, the journal *Expert System with Application* does not appear to require authors to employ the `elsarticle` class -- using the `article` class would appear to be just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{auer2002EXP3,
  author  = {Peter Auer and Nicolò Cesa-Bianchi and Yoav Freund 
            and Robert E. Schapire},
  journal = {SIAM Journal on Computing},
  title   = {The Nonstochastic Multiarmed Bandit Problem},
  year    = {2002}, 
  volume  = {32}, 
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {48--77},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539701398375}, 
  doi     = {10.1137/S0097539701398375},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{auer2002EXP3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am submitting to the journal expert system with application, which requires the APA style.

Comment: It is not impossible to completely link a reference to a URL with BibTeX. So in principle it is not impossible to get closer to what the OP initially asked about even without Elsevier's software. I still agree that it probably wouldn't make a lot of sense to do so, since Elsevier will most likely take care of these kind of things before publication. Even if these is no statement about which class to use and about `biblatex`, I would assume that loading `biblatex` is usually not a great idea for journal submissions.

Comment: Yeah, it would most likely involve writing your own `.bst` file or modifying an existing one. But that is hardly something that can be done only by Elsevier or only with Elsevier software. I was trying to point out that if "what you say you want" in the first sentence is "I want the complete bib entry to be a hyperlink", that can be achieved with the "standard LaTeX toolbox" that is available in all big TeX distributions. As I said, I don't think it is necessary or useful to do so for submission and from the next paragraph onwards I broadly agree with the answer.