# BibTex changes to referer TikTok video in APA style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa7

I am using Daniel A. Weiss code to format my latex document in APA7 style (https://ctan.org/pkg/apa7).

I cannot, however, find out how to correctly format the "Reference" section to reference the video like this:

> Cook, P. [@chemteacherphil]. (2019, November 19). *Alkali salts get lit. #chemistry #chemteacherphil #scienceexperiments #foryou #jobforme #trend #featurethis #science #vibecheck* [Video]. TikTok. https://vm.tiktok.com/xP1r1m

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The `apacite` citation management package and `apacite` bibliography style file implement the APA6 guidelines, not the APA7 guidelines, for bibliographies and citation call-outs. If you must adhere to `APA7` style, you'll need to switch from bibtex/apacite to biber/biblatex-apa. Happily, biblatex "knows" about the `@video` entry type. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612062/5001) for some practical advice on how to go about going the biblatex/apa route. (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Comment: I am using biblatex, but still don't know how to set the code correctly up.

Comment: It is the username that is tricky for me. How do I put the username correctly in?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need a `.bib` entry for APA style with `biblatex-apa` and you don't know how to deal with it, have a look at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib. That file contains `.bib` entries for all reference examples in the APA manual categorised by chapter, section and example number.

That specific file has an example for Instagram posts as well as Youtube videos. Interpolating between them leads us to something like the following

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@video{alkali,
  entrysubtype       = {video},
  author             = {Phillip Cook},
  author+an:username = {1="@chemteacherphil"},
  title              = {Alkali salts get lit.
                        \#chemistry \#chemteacherphil \#scienceexperiments
                        \#foryou \#jobforme \#trend \#featurethis \#science
                        \#vibecheck},
  publisher          = {TikTok},
  url                = {https://vm.tiktok.com/xP1r1m},
  date               = {2019-11-19},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{alkali}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Cook, P. [@chemteacherphil]. (2019, November 19). Alkali salts get lit. #chemistry #chemteacherphil #scienceexperiments #foryou #jobforme #trend #featurethis #science #vibecheck [Video]. TikTok. https://vm.tiktok.com/xP1r1m]